# Convolutional CIFilter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter

My Convolutional filter is not working on a live video preview that I display on the screen. Changing the filter to a Sepia filter displays correctly, but changing it to a `CIConvolution3X3` fails.

```
let weights:[CGFloat] = [1, 0, -1, 2, 0, -2, 1, 0, -1]
result = (CIFilter(name: "CIConvolution3X3", withInputParameters: [
    kCIInputImageKey: result,
    kCIInputWeightsKey: CIVector(values: weights, count: 9),
    kCIInputBiasKey: NSNumber(float: 0.5)
])?.outputImage)!
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I guess the problem is the bias key, since without bias it works for me. Have you figured this out already?

Comment: Any luck identifying why we cannot use inputBias as parameter? The docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIConvolution3X3) explicit specifies inputBias should be passed as an attribute of type CIAttributeTypeDistance. I guess it's automatic setted, but I hope it helps find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! Slightly different context, I was attempting to convert the resulting `CIImage` filtered with `CIConvolution3X3` into a `UIImage`. That failed at runtime and showed the same symptoms as above. (Setting the `inputBias` key to anything other than 0 caused a crash) The exact line of the failure was `self.imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)`.

I did find a solution. The key is to convert the image using a `CIContext`:

```swift
let context = CIContext(options: nil)
guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: rectangle) else { return }
let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
```

Hope this helps